# Input field to the next line with CSS or JavaScript without altering the HTML

Tags: javascript, css, newsletter, survey

I'm working on a Survey and on the system that I work I don't have access to change the HTML directly but I can add CSS or JavaScript to the existing code.

I have the following HTML and I would like the input field to be right underneath the first name. I can only use the ID's as the classes are the same in many other fields that I don't want changing them. I'm a bit stack so if anyone has an idea I would really appreciate..Thanks!

```html
<div id="pnlPersonalDetails2">

</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="surveyquestions">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
        <span id="lbl2"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pd_label">FIRST NAME<span class="red"> *</span></td>
      <td>
        <input name="Name微statictext_2" type="text" id="Name微statictext_2" class="pd_textbox">
      </td>
      <td class="error_label">
        <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're asking how to target specific elements that don't have an `id`, here's how to find the relevant cell: `.surveyquestions tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `+` selector

```css
#pnlPersonalDetails2 + .surveyquestions td {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pnlPersonalDetails2">

</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="surveyquestions">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
        <span id="lbl2"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pd_label">FIRST NAME<span class="red"> *</span></td>
      <td>
        <input name="Name微statictext_2" type="text" id="Name微statictext_2" class="pd_textbox">
      </td>
      <td class="error_label">
        <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="someId"></div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="surveyquestions">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
        <span id="lbl2"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pd_label">FIRST NAME<span class="red"> *</span></td>
      <td>
        <input name="Name微statictext_2" type="text" id="Name微statictext_2" class="pd_textbox">
      </td>
      <td class="error_label">
        <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome, please mark your question as answerd. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps you to achieve the desired style

```
td.pd_label ~ td {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

The same selector (td.pd_label ~ td) works in JavaScript also.